# How do i get area occupied by object in image using cnn model

Tags: python, keras

I'm creating a system which detects slum using satellite imagery. I've created a cnn model(Using keras  and tensorflow backend) which classifies image in its respective class. But how do i get the area occupied by that slum, so that i can test data(Images) of over long period and analyze the growth or decline in that area?

Comment: You must create a U-net model, or a SegNet. Instead of classifying, this model will generate a mask locating the objects. (You must have a true mask as well for training) - Then you just sum the pixels in the mask (if you make it range from 0 to 1)

Comment: I've got something different in my mind. What if i divide the image into small blocks and test each block against the cnn model. So model will predict its class and from that i can create a matrix which contain highValue(1) if that block belongs to required class(slum). would it work?

Comment: Yep, it might work, if you don't care about having an imprecise location such as a block. And you should probably make the blocks overlap, because some blocks might cut the object in half, resulting in no recognition anywhere. Make sure the blocks are big enough to comprehend the entire objecs.